# UIButton touch up inside event only fired if done in title

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am customizing a `UITableViewCell` with several subviews:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
    _mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f)];

    _hiddenOptionsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f)];

    _menuView = [[CellMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 20.0f)];

    [self addSubview:_menuView];
    [self addSubview:_hiddenOptionsView];
    [self addSubview:_mainView];
  }
  return self;
}
```

The class `CellMenuView` is a `UIView` subclass which has two `UIButtons` with their counterpart target actions setup on initialization:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {   
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_menu_bg.png"]];
    [self addSubview:background];

    CGFloat buttonX = frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat buttonY = frame.origin.y + 3.0f;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = frame.size.width / 2.0f;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = 10.0f;

    _editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _editButton.frame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    _editButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _editButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _editButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.5f);
    _editButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22.0f];
    [_editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_editButton];

    _fireButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _fireButton.frame = CGRectMake(buttonWidth, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    _fireButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _fireButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _fireButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.5f);
    _fireButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22.0f];
    [_fireButton setTitle:@"Fire" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_fireButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_fireButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fireButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_fireButton];

    return self;
  }
}
```

I have implemented the target action methods but they aren't being executed. Instead, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` takes precedence over the touch up events inside buttons every time I pressed one of them.

The only way I have been able to fire the events on buttons is making sure that one of the letters in `UIButton's` title is touched (using the simulator, of course).

I must say that `_menuView` is hidden behind the other subviews and shown below the cell when a custom accessory button in cell is pressed. It appears by modifying the Y origin and disappears by setting it to `0.0f` again.

I think it may be related to the view hierarchy, because I haven't had any problems in the past by adding buttons directly to the cell. But I'm just guessing here.

How can I make the events on buttons take precedence over the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Could you include a screenshot of what the row looks like, and how visually the hierarchy looks.

Comment: I can't, the development is "private" right now. But I can edit the question to add more details about the hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And return nil for the indexPath you don't want selected; this will prevent `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from being called on that cell, and (hopefully), your custom action will be called.

**Update:** After implementing this myself (adding borders to the buttons), this is what I have.[image]

The code to achieve this (which is different than yours), is as follows:

*CellMenuView.m*

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _editButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    _editButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    _fireButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    _fireButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

*UITableViewCell subclass*

```
    // Change in height to make it taller
    _menuView = [[TestBtn alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 60.0f)];
```

*UITableViewController subclass*

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100;
```

After testing, mine works as expected. If I click within the white squares, the button action is performed as normal, and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only called when I click outside of the buttons.

I think the issue here might be your button heights/frames, as well as your row height. Add borders to your buttons, to check its clickable area, and increase the height of the button to increase the clickable area.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to capture both events. When selecting a row one action should be executed, but when pressing a button another.

Comment: @elitalon Give `_editButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;` and the same for `_fireButton` a whirl, just before you add it as a subview. Does that do the trick?

Comment: I'm afraid not. In any case, it doesn't explain why the event is captured when pressing just on the title and not in the rest of the button

Comment: Maybe it is because your button is too small? Try to make it bigger and test it.

Comment: @elitalon Updated answer, have a look to see how this applies to you

Comment: You were right about problem with frames. I was using the parent frame origin to compute the origin of button's frame. Thus, it was assigned a negative value and the screen zone where I was touching didn't match with the button "touchable" zone. Thanks!!!